# Calculator Crash

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app for calculating exam note 
When i'm pressing Calculate and there aren't any decimals it shows an answer but if there are decimals it crash

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView Result;
    EditText Number1 , Number2, Number3, Number4, Number5, Number6;
    Button Calculate;

    float result_num;
    int num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Result);

        Number1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Number1);
        Number2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Number2);
        Number3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Number3);
        Number4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Number4);
        Number5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Number5);
        Number6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Number6);

        Calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Calculate);

        Calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                num1 = Integer.parseInt(Number1.getText().toString());
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(Number2.getText().toString());
                num3 = Integer.parseInt(Number3.getText().toString());
                num4 = Integer.parseInt(Number4.getText().toString());
                num5 = Integer.parseInt(Number5.getText().toString());
                num6 = Integer.parseInt(Number6.getText().toString());

                result_num = ((((num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) / 4) * 20) / 100) + ((((num5 + num6) / 2) * 80) / 100);
                Result.setText(String.valueOf(result_num));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: share the xml file and crash you get.

Comment: share you xml file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Float instead of Integer. Integer could not parse (and operate on) numbers with decimal point.

Added: here is error checking code:

```
try {
  num1 = Double.parseDouble(Number1.getText().toString());
  num2 = Double.parseDouble(Number2.getText().toString());
  ...
}
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: no, still crash. When i press on Calculate it shows a black screen and then it redirects me on home screen

Comment: Could you look at logs for exact error (open Logcat tab at the bootom of Android Studio and then run your app)?

Comment: I just tried to create sample code and it works good. Do you use dot "." as a decimal separator? Do not use comma "," - this will crash. Well, to not crash your app, you should catch parser errors:

try {
  num1 = Double.parseDouble(Number1.getText().toString());
  num2 = Double.parseDouble(Number2.getText().toString());
  ...
}
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONGLONG).show();
}

Comment: I added code to the answer because of formatting problems in comment.

Comment: i didn't used comma, my android studio is derp i think

Comment: i still didn't configured out... i will try to remake it from 0. But thanks anyway for your help i marked as the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are trying to parse `Double` or `Float` value into `Integer` type, on the code below:

```
Integer.parseInt(Number1.getText().toString());
```

Your code will not work on decimal values. But you can change it to Double value like this:

```
double value1 = Double.parseDouble(Number1.getText().toString());
```